# Docker Registry doesn't work with Let's encrypt configuration

Tags: docker-registry

I'm trying to run Docker Registry from docker image with [Let's encrypt configuration](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#letsencrypt):

```
docker run -d -p 443:5000 --name registry \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_CACHEFILE=/etc/docker/registry/letsencrypt.json \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@example.com \
registry:2
```

but it produces this error:

```
time="2023-05-02T12:26:08.615956213Z" level=fatal msg="create client: get directory at 'https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': failed to get "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": Get "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": dial tcp: lookup acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host"
```

I've tried to google search `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org`; it looks like it was [deprecated](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cannot-resolve-acme-v01/166715) (for some time now), but there is no new version on Docker Hub.

Is this project abandon for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the upstream of the registry with fixes that have been merged but not released:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/distribution/distribution.git
cd distribution
docker build -t registry:latest .
```

And then deploy `registry:latest` (or change the name to your own image name).

Answer (score 2):

ACMEv1 was completely [EOL](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430) in June 2021.

To move to ACMEv2 you can look at [this github issue](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3041#issuecomment-573302505), which shows a possible way to include certbot to resolve the issue. Other documentation by Letsencrypt can be found [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/).

Excerpt from the github issue:

Installing Certbot:

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --standalone

...

 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

...
```

Providing the Certificate:

```
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR="0.0.0.0:443" \
  -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem \
  registry:2
```

For a more complete answer i suggest looking at the details of the linked GitHub comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing up the GitHub issue page to the table. Using `certbot` works but still leaves a problem of certificate renewal that requires manual action.

[Few comments below](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3041#issuecomment-654786830) contributors suggested recompiling the image with an updated version, but their solutions seem to have issues.

I'm posting a fixed version of it in the `dockerfile` below:

```
FROM golang:alpine as fixed
RUN apk update; apk add --no-cache bash git openssh make
RUN git clone https://github.com/docker/distribution
WORKDIR distribution
RUN make binaries

FROM registry:latest
COPY  --from=fixed /go/distribution/bin/registry /bin/registry
```

to run:

```
docker run -d -p 443:5000 --name registry \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_CACHEFILE=/etc/docker/registry/letsencrypt.json \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@example.com \
registry:fixed
```

Comment: There's a Dockerfile in distribution/distribution. If you're going to clone and build it, why not use their Dockerfile instead of making one that extends an old image that was built from that same Dockerfile?

Comment: It's a valid point; I didn't look into their repo close enough. This solves everything. Thanks!

Comment: If you add it below I will mark problem as solved, and we can close it. (it's your credit after all)